# actionValidateCustomerAddressFormAfter triggers the hook before Prestashop's form validation

Tags: prestashop, hook, prestashop-1.7

In my Prestashop 1.7 Website, I have a front-end address edition form (allowing my customer to edit its postal addresses). I want to execute a hook after Prestashop has decided weither the data the user typed are correct or not (*e.g.* postcode contains digits only). I thought it could be done by using:

`$this->registerHook('actionValidateCustomerAddressFormAfter');` in addition to:
`public function hookActionValidateCustomerAddressForm($data) { /* Here is the triggered hook */ }`

But the triggered hook `hookActionValidateCustomerAddressForm` is executed even when the user submits bad data (*e.g.* postcode with at least one letter).

It means that my program doesn't wait for Prestashop's data verification.

What is the way to execute this hook after Prestashop decides if the  data is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hook is executed in `validate()` function from `CustomerAddessForm` class:

```
public function validate()
{
    $is_valid = true;

    if (($postcode = $this->getField('postcode'))) {
        if ($postcode->isRequired()) {
            $country = $this->formatter->getCountry();
            if (!$country->checkZipCode($postcode->getValue())) {
                $postcode->addError($this->translator->trans(
                    'Invalid postcode - should look like "%zipcode%"',
                    array('%zipcode%' => $country->zip_code_format),
                    'Shop.Forms.Errors'
                ));
                $is_valid = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (($hookReturn = Hook::exec('actionValidateCustomerAddressForm', array('form' => $this))) !== '') {
        $is_valid &= (bool) $hookReturn;
    }

    return $is_valid && parent::validate();
}
```

This hook is executed always (no matter if form is valid or not) and PrestaShop doesn't send you `$is_valid`  as a parameter. So the only thing that you can do is to do the same validation than PrestaShop if you want to know if form is valid.

Comment: I can override this method `CustomerAddressForm`::`validate` in order to execute this hook only if the form is valide, no?

Comment: Maybe not, according to: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/overrides/    -   Let me know if I'm wrong?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler yes, you can override this class

Comment: I Googled it but found no way to override a form class. Would it be possible to extend your answer to include it? Do you want me to open a new question?