# Is there a hook triggered when the frontend PS1.7 user deletes a postal address in its account?

Tags: prestashop, hook, prestashop-1.7

`hookActionValidateCustomerAddressForm` is only called when he creates or changes an address.

According to https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/, there is probably not any hook to handle the case I describe in the title of this SO Question.

Am I wrong? If yes: what would be the hook? If no: how could I deal with this use case (I really need to execute a program when the user triggers this event)?

Exemple of what the hook I'm looking for would be: `actionDeleteCustomerAddressAfter` (of course it doesn't exist)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [actionValidateCustomerAddressFormAfter triggers the hook before Prestashop's form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60429732/actionvalidatecustomeraddressformafter-triggers-the-hook-before-prestashops-for)

Comment: @joseantgv no, it's completely different! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hooks from `ObjectModel` called when you add or update any other object, in your case `Address`.

If you check functions `add()`:

```
public function add($auto_date = true, $null_values = false)
{
    ...

    // @hook actionObject*AddBefore
    Hook::exec('actionObjectAddBefore', array('object' => $this));
    Hook::exec('actionObject' . $this->getFullyQualifiedName() . 'AddBefore', array('object' => $this));

    ...

    // @hook actionObject*AddAfter
    Hook::exec('actionObjectAddAfter', array('object' => $this));
    Hook::exec('actionObject' . $this->getFullyQualifiedName() . 'AddAfter', array('object' => $this));

    ...
}
```

and `update()`;

```
public function update($null_values = false)
{
    // @hook actionObject*UpdateBefore
    Hook::exec('actionObjectUpdateBefore', array('object' => $this));
    Hook::exec('actionObject' . $this->getFullyQualifiedName() . 'UpdateBefore', array('object' => $this));

    ...

    // @hook actionObject*UpdateAfter
    Hook::exec('actionObjectUpdateAfter', array('object' => $this));
    Hook::exec('actionObject' . $this->getFullyQualifiedName() . 'UpdateAfter', array('object' => $this));

    ...
}
```

Then you can use the following hooks in your module:

`actionObjectAddressAddBefore`

`actionObjectAddressAddAfter`

`actionObjectAddressUpdateBefore`

`actionObjectAddressUpdateAfter`

Comment: actionObjectAddressDeleteBefore works (foundf in `ObjectModel`'s delete function, way to find it: ` public function delete()
    {
        // @hook actionObject*DeleteBefore
        Hook::exec('actionObjectDeleteBefore', array('object' => $this));
  Hook::exec('actionObject' . $this->getFullyQualifiedName() . 'DeleteBefore', array('object' => $this));
  echo '<pre>';
   echo 'actionObject' . $this->getFullyQualifiedName() . 'DeleteBefore';
   var_dump('actionObject' . $this->getFullyQualifiedName() . 'DeleteBefore');
  echo '</pre>';exit; ` )

Answer (score 1):

There is no hook for this.

A worse solution to search for the method which delete the postal address, and insert your code there.

A better solution is: Create a new hook (even `actionDeleteCustomerAddressAfter`), and trigger the hook in the method which delete the postal address.

```
        Hook::exec('actionDeleteCustomerAddressAfter ', array('id_customer' => (int)$customer->id));
```

Comment: Thank you! However I must not modify (nor override) the method which deletes the postal address. So your 2nd solution doesn't match my needs, in this specific working context. Of course, approx. same answer for your "worse solution" :). But your answer was admissible and useful :)